# error when saving a file in an elixir project (elixirLS.projectDir)

Tags: elixir

I have the following error when saving an elixir file with visual studio code

> No mixfile found in project. To use a subdirectory, set
> `elixirLS.projectDir` in your settings

I have thus updated the User/settings.json (In windows) file such as

```
{
    "elixirLS.projectDir": "C:\\CodeTraining\\Elixir-intro"
}
```

But I still get the error

Any idea ?

By the way, I have the same error when using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*ElixirLS* requires `mix` project, it does not work properly with plain files. So start with creating the project

```sh
mix new intro
cd intro
code .
```

Now in `intro` folder *ElixirLS* would be happy. You still can create random [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) files and/or scripts there to play with.

Comment: P.S.: if you have an existing directory, you can do `cd <directory>` and then `mix new .`

Answer (score 2):

Since I landed here searching for an answer to this but for Vim, I'm gonna share what will fix the error on Vim

The error is caused by the language client incorrectly setting the project root based on the first file that you opened. For example, if you open `mix.exs` first, this is printed to the Vim output:

```
LanguageClient project root: /Users/joe/Downloads/test
```

However, if you open something else (like `lib/test.ex`) you get the following:

```
LanguageClient project root: /Users/joe/Downloads/test/lib
```

So, in order to fix this, add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:LanguageClient_rootMarkers = {
    \ 'elixir': ['mix.exs'],
    \ }
```

Or if you use `coc.nvim`, add this to your `.vimrc` instead

```
autocmd FileType elixir let b:coc_root_patterns = ['mix.exs']
```

This will correctly set the project root based on the location of `mix.exs` for the purposes of `ElixirLS`